# templates to use with Zend/CodeIgniter framework?

Tags: templates, zend-framework, codeigniter, themes

I'm trying to build an online recruitment site using the Zend/CodeIgniter framework. I wanted to know which of the two frameworks is the easiest to use and which gives support for templates.I want to write minimum code as possible.

I has hoping I could use a template or some form of CMS that would allow me to quickly create (or automatically provide) an admin and user profile section. Users will need to enter their CV details, modify their account, search and apply for jobs. The admin will then be able to search for applicants based on qualifications, job role, etc. 
are there any templates I can use on top of the Zend or CodeIgniter framework to get done the majority of the work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With your needs i like to go with **cakePHP**, it just need models to be ready and with scaffolding admin panel is good, with Auth and causal baking user section is ready too

With **Zend**, it usually takes some time to get the things done.

Comment: thanks. so it should be easy to add a template/theme in cakephp and work from there? can i use template such as those available on http://www.freelayouts.com/websites/html-templates?